# Ubuntu 20.04.01 not booting after kernel update

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I just updated my PC that is running the latest version of Ubuntu (20.04.01). I made a system update and that update included also a kernel update (from kernel 5.4.0-42-generic to 5.4.0-45-generic).

My PC rebooted after the update and I got stuck at a screen telling me some errors, and that the device with the `UUID=xxxxx...` could not be found. I was in a "BusyBox" shell and didn't now what to do.

For now I just switched to the "old" kernel version when I boot up Ubuntu and it boots up just fine. I had a look at `/etc/fstab` if the UUIDs match the real UUIDs and that's the case.

I think that the new kernel version has some troubles with detecting my NVMe drive. I've installed Ubuntu on an NVMe drive and with the previous kernel it works, the new kernel doesn't work. My NVMe drive wasn't even listed in `/dev/`.

Is there a way to "delete" the new kernel version or make the old version the default one? I don't want to chose the kernel version every time I boot up my PC.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd better report this on ubuntu bugtracker directly

Comment: You can change the defaults with `grub-customizer`. It's pretty straightforward. You can also `sudo apt-get --auto-remove purge linux-******` (with your version) a specific kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Update: The bug is now fixed on version 5.4.0-48.

---

I just want to mention that similar bug report exists: [Cannot boot after updating kernel to version 5.4.0-45](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1894378). No solution yet at this point, will update this post accordingly.

---

To make grub remember your last boot choice, follow this post: [How to get grub2 to remember last choice?](https://askubuntu.com/a/149572)

Comment: Well written and proper link. Have my point to gain rep!