# How to fix Debian 11 not booting after kernel upgrade?

Tags: filesystems, boot, linux-kernel, grub2, root-filesystem

My Debian 11 shipped with version 5.10 of the Linux kernel. I wanted a newer one, so I downloaded 5.15 from [here](https://www.kernel.org/), extracted the tar file, copied over the existing configuration, ran `make menuconfig`, followed by `make -j24`, and then `sudo make install`. I also did `sudo update-grub`. But now it does this whenever it boots. If I chose the old kernel in grub, it boots fine.

The `SPCP: Unexpected SPCR Access Width` message still happened with 5.10 (which I can still boot to), so I don't think it matters. Doing `update-initramfs -u` didn't help either, it still gives this error.

Most of the existing advice I've seen says that the UUID is wrong, but the old kernel boots fine, so that makes me think the boot partitions are fine. How can I fix this so I can boot successfully using the 5.15 kernel?

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607694/495409) indicates it could be caused by a bug, but my kernel versions (5.10, which works, and 5.15, which fails) are both newer than what was mentioned there.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: do you really need 5.15? because 5.14 is available in bullseye backports

Comment: @Bravo Nope. I'd never compiled my own kernel, so I opted to try. But I don't have a good reason other than that. If you know how to use backports (I've never done that) to get 5.14, feel free to post an answer. 5.15 would be better, but 5.14 is fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it working. First, I installed the dependicies:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev flex bison libelf-dev bc dwarves binutils binutils-dev -y
```

Next, I by making a folder for the kernel (`~/kernel`). I went into the folder, and downloaded the tarball for the 5.15 kernel:

```
$ wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.15.13.tar.xz
```

Then I went into the folder from the tarball (`cd linux-5.15.13/`). I took the old config from the 5.10 kernel and re-used it:

```
$ cat /boot/config-5.10.0-10-amd64 > .config
```

Run menuconfig:

```
$ make menuconfig -j24
```

I went down, and disabled `Enable loadable module support` (navigate to it with the arrow keys, and then press <kbd>Space</kbd> so there is no `*` in the box next to it anymore). Also, navigate to `Cryptographics API -> Certificates for Signature Checking`, and where it says `Additional X.509 keys for default system keyring`, make sure that is empty. By default, for me, it said `debian/certs/debian-uefi-certs.pem`. Make sure that field is empty. Then, save (with the filename `.config`) and exit the `menuconfig` tool.

I then compiled the kernel. Remember to do this with `sudo`. Otherwise it won't work right later.

```
$ sudo make -j24
```

And then install it (remember to use `sudo` for this, too):

```
$ sudo make install -j24
```

It may give some warnings, but you can ignore them. Now do `sudo update-grub`. Reboot, and it works!

---

The resolution changed, so I ended up putting this at the end of the `/etc/default/grub` file to fix it. Do note that the mode (`0x031b`) will probobly be different for you, so use `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer` to determine the resolution options. You may need to do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install hwinfo` to install it.

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=0x031b,1280x1024x24,auto
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

If you changed the resolution as shown above, do `sudo update-grub` and reboot to use those new settings.